# Convertir un Uint8List a un archivo File en Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart

Quisiera saber si alguien de aquí ha trabajado con Flutter web y la librería [FilePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) para permitir escoger archivos. Normalmente con el resultado del picker se puede extraer el nombre del archivo, los bytes en `Uint8List`.
En mobile también se puede extraer el path, pero en web es imposible por la librería *dart:io*.
Necesito crear un archivo tipo `File()` a través del picker, con solo la data que tengo, pero no he hallado la manera.

Si alguien lo ha podido hacer y me pueda decir me serviría mucho. O tal vez alguna manera de convertir los datos `Uint8List` a `File` (ya probé este método `File.fromRawPath()` pero nada.)

Comment: Podrías probar la segunda respuesta de este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793993/how-to-convert-uint8list-image-to-file-image-for-upload-in-flutter-web

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento?

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que el archivo Uint8List es un archivo Raw puro y duro, que se guarda en el "aire" (cache) tendras que tener acceso al cache donde esta guardado. En `Flutter` usamos una biblioteca llamada Path Provider.  https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Al instalar esta dependencia podras hacer lo siguiente:

```
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    
    final tu_archivo_Uint8List = funcion();
    
    final directorio_en_cache = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    
    File tu_archivo_file = await File('${directorio_en_cache.path}/$nombre_de_tu_archivo.extencion').create();

tu_archivo_file.writeAsBytesSync(tu_archivo_Uint8List);


//Tu archivo Uint8List ya es un File
```

Comment: Si, lo malo es que ese paquete no funciona para flutter web, que es en lo que estoy trabajando, en sí el paquete dart:io ya se complica en web para este tipos de conversiones. Gracias igualmente